# Shells initialization files

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I know that in linux(usually) such initialization file will be .bashrc (bash is the default shell), for OSX it will be .bash_profile. But there are also different shells, like zsh.

So I wonder, if I will have bash as the default shell, with it's configuration in .bashrc, and then I'll decide to run `exec zsh` - what file would I need to edit to specify the initialization steps for zsh specifically? Are there separate files for different kinds of shells that are running while initialization a new terminal?

I tried to add some aliases before to my .bashrc to achieve the same result:

```
alias switch_to_zsh="exec zsh; source zsh_config.sh"
```

But after switching to zsh it forgets about `source zsh_config.sh` part.

Comment: Nothing after the `exec` will be run (if `exec` succeeds) as `exec` will *replace* the existing process with something that has no idea about whatever other commands were in queue with the previous process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from zsh manual:

```
   Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  If the shell is a  login
   shell,  commands  are  read  from  /etc/zsh/zprofile  and  then  $ZDOT‐
   DIR/.zprofile.  Then, if the shell is interactive,  commands  are  read
   from /etc/zsh/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc.  Finally, if the shell is
   a login shell, /etc/zsh/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.
```

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdy) lists the startup files for the most common *nix shells. For zsh the equivalent to `.bashrc` is `.zshrc`.